# Do I need a password for users who login via Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a website that allows a person to create an account with username/password. Once its created they can login and add their own content. Im now thinking about allowing them to login via their facebook profile, so when they go to my login there will be a button that says login with facebook. Then a window will popup to give permission to my facebook app so I can get their info. Once I do that do I need them to create a password still? Or once they initially give permission for their account I dont need a password, so when they come back to the site they just need to reconnect to their facebook profile? Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the latter is true, and they don't need a password.

Answer (score 0):

My buddy did the same thing. He has his setup to create a random password if they login via facebook as a precaution if they want to later login not via facebook but via their email or username then they have to recover the password.

Answer (score 0):

No, you dont need to save any password for facebook login. Facebook login box works great if you have implementes Facebook api correctly.